# Remove specific file from input type file (multiple)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, file-upload

I have a input type file (also multiple) for uploading images .
i wanna remove specific index of filelist in that input .

my code looks something like below .

```
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="file" multiple name="name" id="pho" value="" />
  </form>

  <div id="view">

  </div>

  $("#pho").change(function () {
        var files = document.getElementById("pho").files;
        var img = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            img += "<img class='img-view' src='" + window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]) + "' />";
        }
        $("#view").html('').append(img);
    });
```

How can i do it ?

is it even possible to remove a file from filelist and put it in input  ?

if not is there any library or plugin to use for this problem ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Please include any code or steps you have tried.

Comment: You can not alter the file input values

Comment: @epascarello isn't there any library for uploading images  with remove option ? ( exept dropzone.js )

Comment: LIbrary? I do not know libraries. You can code it so you maintain a list and remove it from  your list, but you can not alter the values inside of the input itself.

Comment: @epascarello allright , but i should store the new list in somewhere and post it , the main problem it when i want to assign the new flielist to another input

Comment: You can not assign values to a type="file", that is a security issue. What are you actually trying to do? You want a preview and want to remove items. Are you submitting it to the server?

Comment: @epascarello yes i'm previewing them and post them to server , also i want to have remove option before sending to server

Comment: Well issue is you can not alter it so you would need to change how you submit it to the server. FormData is going to be what you will need to use.

Comment: @epascarello thank for your help